# Microsoft graph teams, 403 on posting message in chats

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We are using `beta` endpoint to post message to meeting chat

endpoint is
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/chats/{chatId}/messages`

but it is returning 403 Forbidden

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 23b6427c-a3f2-4b53-85e4-4acc491ffa8e
client-request-id: b59322c2-b338-4862-8448-a3271c116ac1

{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "23b6427c-a3f2-4b53-85e4-4acc491ffa8e",
            "date": "2020-05-27T07:02:39"
        }
    }
}
```

#### permission scopes are

```
Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared Chat.ReadWrite Directory.Read.All Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite Group.ReadWrite.All Mail.Send MailboxSettings.Read Notes.ReadWrite.All openid profile Sites.ReadWrite.All Tasks.ReadWrite User.Read User.ReadBasic.All
```

It is working for everybody except for this user

Comment: I guess, you are using delegated permissions - so perhaps the user has no right to post to the channel, because he or she is not in the team?

Comment: @Homungus , its not a team meeting , but a adhoc chat meeting

Comment: OK, so if it works for all other users there is something special for this single user, e.g. from another tenant, using microsoft account instead of work/school account, has limited rights, so many possibilities here. keep in mind: rights limiting is interesction between user rights and scope.